# How do I center numbers in a table from Google Visualization API?

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I am currently trying to help put together a website to display a lot of data from Google Sheets. In this I figured I would use the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter) to format the data so that I could show it in the way I would like. I have now found this incredibly frustrating.

What I would like to do is center a column of numbers, however all of the numbers will still right align when I center them using css.

The css is being applied like so: `.center { text-align: center; }` and I am applying the css as described by Google:

```
var cssClassNames = {
'headerRow': 'header-row',
'tableRow': 'table-row',
'oddTableRow': 'odd-table-row',
'selectedTableRow': 'selected-table-row',
'hoverTableRow': 'hover-table-row',
'headerCell': 'header-cell center',
'tableCell': 'table-cell',
'rowNumberCell': ''};

function loadGoogleDriveTable(elementID, documentKey, range, sheetID) {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=' + documentKey + '&range=' + range + '&usp=drive_web&gid=' + sheetID + '#');
    query.send(function(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var options = { 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames };
        var data = response.getDataTable();
        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(elementID));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

The tables load with all of the appropriate data, but don't change how they look.[image: Here is a picture of what is happening.]

Any help on this would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this happens because even though your cell is displayed with your custom class, as its a number cell it also gives the cell a `google-visualization-table-td-number` class, which sets the `text-align:right`. To fix it, just change your style to ovewrite it: `text-align: center !important;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you wouldn't happen to know how to remove the 'float: left' from the style of progress bars would you?

Comment: Which progress bars? As long as you overwrite the css property, you can  'remove' it

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. There is a span inside of the number when you use a bar to display data in a contextual manner.

Comment: Would need to see an example

Comment: I have a full question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759597/how-do-i-center-a-bar-format-from-google-visualization).