# How do I center a Bar Format from Google Visualization?

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540649/how-do-i-center-numbers-in-a-table-from-google-visualization-api) where I asked how to center a number (i.e. text return) from the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/). The new issue I am having is that I want to show progress bars for a specific piece of data, and I would like to center them. I am using the [Bar Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#barformatter). However, my CSS does not seem to work. I know that I should be able to apply CSS to a specific tag within a named element (or I believe I can).

Here is picture of the current site: 
[image: Current Site]

I believe if I can remove `float: left;` as inherited from the google process and add `margin: 0 auto;` this will all work. [Here is a JSFiddle of my work so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/pyroticblaziken/a8e3re72/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, removing the `float:left;` works well.

With reference to your question [How do I center numbers in a table from Google Visualization API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540649/how-do-i-center-numbers-in-a-table-from-google-visualization-api), the solution is simple as stated in one of its anwser.

You need to overwrite the css inherited by the API for the **span** tag inside the **td**.

```
span{
    float:none !important;
}
```

Here's the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/a8e3re72/5/